# Cypress Custom TypeScript Command is not a Function

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I am implementing a custom Cypress command in TypeScript:

```
// support/commands.ts
const login = () => {
    console.log('Logging in...');
};

Cypress.Commands.add('login', login);

declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable {
        login: typeof login;
    }
}
```

I try to call it using:

```
describe('Login Scenario', () => {
    it('should allow a user to login', () => {
        cy.visit('/');
        cy.login();
    });
});
```

Yet, it seems the command is not set up:

```
TypeError: cy.login is not a function
```

If I write the command in pure JavaScript (removing the namespace declaration and updating the call to `(cy as any).login();`, it works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is your `support/commands.js` included in your `support/index.js`?

Comment: Is there any answer that worked for you?

Comment: import './commands';
in support/index.ts

Answer (score 17):

I fixed it by adding `index.d.ts` file in my commands folder. In this file I added something like this:

```
import { MyCustomType } from '../Types';

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
      login(): Chainable<MyCustomType>;
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't import or export anything, just omit global namespace declaration:

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
    login(): Chainable<MyCustomType>;
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that it won't work with Typesciprt < 2.3, because default generics type has to be supported.

Comment: Is there any additional step to follow? Maybe you could give insights about your tsconfig?

Comment: It should work right away. Currently, I don't work with Cypress so I can't share my tsconfig. Are you sure that your file is named with `.d.ts` suffix?

Comment: This only works for me if the index.d.ts file is in the same folder as the spec.

Comment: Do you know why we need `declare global` when we are importing something? I'm importing cypress-wait-until

Comment: If you don't have any import/export, a file is considered to be in the global namespace Take a look here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38592#issue-619054264, or here, point 7 https://www.techatbloomberg.com/blog/10-insights-adopting-typescript-at-scale/

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue and all solutions I found did not work for me. Having done everything from the official Cypress documentation and other solutions here I still got the error `cy.login is not a function`.

The problem was that I renamed every `.js` file to `.ts` and `cypress/support/index.ts` was not loaded any more, because per default Cypress only loads the JavaScript one. To fix it, you need to change it to `.ts` in `cypress.json` like that (the same with plugins file):

```
{
  "supportFile": "cypress/support/index.ts",
  "pluginsFile": "cypress/plugins/index.ts"
}
```

You can also add the part with `declare namespace Cypress {...` to `commands.ts` instead of creating an `index.d.ts` file, to have the declaration and implementation in the same file

Comment: Did you also have to change anything in your tsconfig file? I've tried setting the `supportFile` and `pluginsFile` paths to the `.ts` file, but I get the Cypress error:

"Your pluginsFile is set to `/tests/e2e/plugins/index.ts`, but either the file is missing, it contains a syntax error, or threw an error when required. The pluginsFile must be a .js or .coffee file."

Comment: My `cypress/tsconfig.json` looks like that:

`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}`. PS: comments do not allow proper block formatting

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I use and I do not have to add

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
```

at the top of every file.

I have my custom typings under `<projectroot>/cypress/support/index.d.ts`

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    getByDataTest(tag: string): Chainable<any>
  }
}
```

And my `<projectroot>/cypress/tsconfig.json` looks like

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "../node_modules",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
    "typeRoots": ["./support"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

And TypeScript is finally happy

```
describe('when I want to select by data test tag', () => {
  it('should select by data test tag', () => {
    cy.getByDataTest('yolo').should('exist')
  });
});
```

Comment: May I know where do you write the implementation of the method `getByDataTest` ?

Comment: @RajKon

const getDataTag = (tag: string, value: any) => `[data-${tag}="${value}"]`;
const getDataTestTag = (value: any) => getDataTag('test', value);
Cypress.Commands.add('getByDataTest', tag => cy.get(getDataTestTag(tag)));

Comment: you can use either `types` or `typeRoots`, not both. see http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types

Comment: And what if I use only js files, not typescript with cypress? Then namespace declarations can;t be used

Comment: You might wanna restart VS, just in case if you still see the red squiggles from your linter.

Answer (score 4):

Custom commands might not get imported, In cypress version 10 using angular/typescript schematic, there is a e2e.ts rather than index in support folder that imports the commands, if not then it needs the index.ts file with below import command, also it needs to be added to cypress config as supportFile:

```
// cypress/support/e2e.ts 

// When a command from ./commands is ready to use, import with `import './commands'` syntax

   import './commands';
```

It might already be commented in the file as well

Comment: All the other answers are mostly obsolete. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in my project which is using NX. I installed Cypress for testing my Angular app, and it generated the following files:

```
frontend/
├─ cypress/
│  ├─ e2e/
│  ├─ fixtures/
│  ├─ support/
│  │  ├─ app.po.ts
│  │  ├─ commands.js
│  │  ├─ commands.ts
│  │  ├─ component-index.html
│  │  ├─ component.js
│  │  ├─ e2e.ts
```

Inside component.js there was an `import './commands'` line which was importing the `commands.js` file by default instead of `commands.ts` which is where I declared my custom command. I removed commands.js and it worked. I hope this helps somebody.