# Problem adding a new method to Promise prototype

Tags: typescript

typescript 3.1.2

I have searched through many stack overflow questions and online articles, and I've seen the same types of answers many times to questions about modifying existing typescript classes such as `String` and `Array<T>`, but I can't seem to get this working for the `Promise<T>` class.

I've already read through all of these, no luck:

[How to define global function in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47736473/how-to-define-global-function-in-typescript)

[How to add file with extending prototype in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004290/how-to-add-file-with-extending-prototype-in-typescript)

[How to extend String Prototype and use it next, in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877156/how-to-extend-string-prototype-and-use-it-next-in-typescript/39877446)

[Cypress Custom TypeScript Command is not a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694218/cypress-custom-typescript-command-is-not-a-function)

[Extending Array in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802383/extending-array-in-typescript)

---

Here's my current code (I've tried  many variations):

*Promise.d.ts*

```
declare global {
    export interface Promise<T> {
        catchWrapper(): Promise<T>;
    }
}
```

*Promise.ts*

```
Promise.prototype.catchWrapper = function<T>(this: Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    return Promise.prototype.catch.apply(this, [e => {
        console.log(`catch wrapper. ${e}`);
        }]);
    }
```

(I've tried adding `export { }` in Promise.ts, it doesn't help)

*another.ts*

```
import '../theDir/Promise'

anAsyncMethod().catchWrapper();
```

This all compiles but I continually get runtime errors:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: anAsyncMethod().catchWrapper is not a function`

Is my implementation of catchWrapper() not being matched up to the declaration of the interface by the compiler?

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal here was to have the extension method in a lib and use it in other apps. After messing around with it for a while I ended up using this solution. Leaving any part of it out causes runtime errors.

By putting both the declaration and definition in the .ts file and then importing the *file* (anywhere..!) in the lib my other project is then able to use the extension method as soon as it imports anything from the lib.

Here's what the final code looks like:

In the lib project:

*Promise.ts*

```
Promise.prototype.catchExtension = function<T>(this : Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    return Promise.prototype.catch.apply(this, [() => { /*do stuff*/ }]);
}

declare global {
    interface Promise<T> {
        catchExtension(): Promise<T>;
    }
}
export { }
```

*lib.ts*

```
import './Promise';
export { } from './Promise';
// The rest of the exports
export { Example } from './Example'
```

In the main app:

```
// Import anything from lib
import { Example } from '@mylib'
// import { } from '@mylib' <--- doesn't work

const x: Promise<string> = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => { reject(); });
x.catchExtension();
// It works! We end up in `() => { /*do stuff*/ }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the content or `Promise.d.ts` to this:

```
declare interface Promise<T> {
  catchWrapper (): Promise<T>;
}
```

Also should not need to import the `.d.ts` if it is located either in your `rootDir` or in one of `typeRoots` specified in the config file.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with that code. But, that code does compile without requiring the `export { }` statement.

Comment: Also, you are correct about not needing the `import`

Comment: I ended up not being able to use this style of code. I found a solution through experimentation though, I've posted it below.